# insert values of query into table, even if no result in query (insert 0 values)

Tags: mysql, select, insert-into

I am trying to solve a probably simple thing, being no expert at all @ mysql

I have this first table 'online_players'

```
mysql> show columns from online_players;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Agent             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Name              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Alias             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Begin_Date        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LastBalanceUpdate | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Session_minutes   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Balance           | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Product           | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

which is droped, recreated and value inserted every 3 minutes, it shows players on a  website currently playing...

I then have this table 'players_count' :

```
mysql> show columns from players_count;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| date_count    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| players_count | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| product       | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| avg_balance   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

When the table online_players is updated, the table players_count is updated with a specific insert:

```
USE livefeed;
INSERT INTO players_count(
date_count,players_count,product, avg_balance)
SELECT
now(),
count(Name) as Players,
Product,
Avg(Balance)
FROM
online_players
GROUP BY Product;
```

It works ok when at list 1 player is online:

```
mysql> select * from players_count
    -> ;
+---------------------+---------------+---------+-------------+----+
| date_count          | players_count | product | avg_balance | id |
+---------------------+---------------+---------+-------------+----+
| 2016-03-28 17:09:02 | 2             | USD     | 0.06        | 1  |
| 2016-03-28 17:12:01 | 1             | USD     | 0.12        | 2  |
| 2016-03-28 17:15:00 | 1             | USD     | 0.12        | 3  |
| 2016-03-28 17:18:00 | 1             | USD     | 0.12        | 4  |
| 2016-03-28 17:21:01 | 1             | USD     | 0.12        | 5  |
| 2016-03-28 17:24:00 | 1             | USD     | 0.12        | 6  |
+---------------------+---------------+---------+-------------+----+
6 rows in set (0.21 sec)
```

But I would also like to record a row in table players_count when NO player is online even if my query above = 0, for example:

```
+---------------------+---------------+---------+-------------+----+
| date_count          | players_count | product | avg_balance | id |
+---------------------+---------------+---------+-------------+----+
| 2016-03-28 18:01:00 | 0             | USD     | 0           | 7  |
| 2016-03-28 18:01:00 | 0             | FUN     | 0           | 8  |
```

I use the table players_count to generate "real time" graphs and need to have 0 values for every specific date.

It might be simple but I have not found any solution online...
How shoud I modify my Insert/query to do this?
Thanks for your help

Comment: join against your product table? you can't produce records out of nothing - if a table's empty, you can't squeeze data out of it. so join another table and use that as a "scaffold" to hang your 0-counts on.

Comment: there is no product table... table is a field reflecting currency. I have to do this with these 2 tables only...

Comment: well, then you can't. like I said, you can't produce data out of nothingness. if there's no records in the db, then you can't select anything.

Comment: well to put a 0 in a table when a query result is empty in another table, puting just a NOW() in the date field does not seem to me to produce data out of nothingness!!